Understanding $C_n(X)$
I have this quote from Allen Hatcher's book Algebraic Topology:

A singular $n$-simplex in a space $X$ is by definition just a map $\sigma:\Delta^n\rightarrow X$. [...] All that is required is that $\sigma$ be continuous. Let $C_n(X)$ be the free abelian group with basis the set of singular $n$-simplices in $X$. Elements of $C_n(X)$ [...] are finite formal sums $\sum_i n_i\sigma_i$ for $n_i\in\mathbb Z$ and $\sigma_i:\Delta^n\rightarrow X$.

This makes it seem like the $\sigma_i$ are countable. Are they? And if they are, how to select the $\sigma_i$ from all the $\sigma$, which intuitively seem uncountable to me?

If $X$ is uncountable, then $C_0(X)$ is uncountable: it has one basis element for each element of $X$. If $X$ is, for example, a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>0$, then $C_k(X)$ will be uncountable for all $k$. (That is, its basis of continuous functions $\Delta^k \to X$ is uncountable.)

What about the second part of my question then?

Your second question starts, “if they are” [countable]. Since they are not countable, that question doesn’t seem to apply. All maps $\sigma$ are available, not are specially selected.

Note that each element in the direct sum is a finite sum, so it is appropriate to use $i$ for an index.

Ah, I see my mistake now. I assumed $i$ was running over $\mathbb Z$ because of $n_i\in\mathbb Z$
